# C# Best practices in object initialization

Tags: c#, object

I have an Order object and the Order object contains a Person object which stores the information about the person who placed the order. When I populate the Order object am I supposed to populate the Person object as well? Or would I be better off calling order.GetPerson() whenever I need to access to the person who placed the order.

Comment: Suppose it depends on the design.  If an `Order` requires that it has a non-null `Person` at all times, (EDIT: and it doesn't get assigned new persons later) then having it passed in via its constructor and validated as non-null is generally a good place to start.

Comment: How does the last sentence fit with the rest of your question? `order.GetPerson()` suggests that the `order.Person` property has been set previously (and that's what your question seems to be about).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant was when the order.GetPerson() gets called for the first time it will attempt to retrieve the person information from database, initialize and return the person object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider the [`LazyLoading`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) approach. So that the Person data will be fetched and loaded when it is required (queried for the first time)

> Lazy loading is a design pattern commonly used in computer programming
>   to defer initialization of an object until the point at which it is
>   needed

Answer (score 0):

If resources are an issue then Shyju's answer makes sense.  Otherwise, if you always know the person that's associated with the Order then, yes, populate it.  Also, it's a good idea to make objects immutable as often as possible, and you probably can in this case; i.e. pass the person in through the constructor and never change it.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by Chris Sinclair indicates, it does come down to your design and considering how frequently you'll need the Person objects.  If nearly every time you load Orders, you want the associated Persons as well (for display, or calculations, etc.) then it makes sense to always load the Persons to limit the number of database calls.  If you hardly ever need the Person data, then it makes more sense to get the Person data in a late-bound/lazy-loading manner.

Consider this example.  You retrieve all orders to display them in a grid.  But when you populate the grid, you also want to display the Person info per order.  If you load the Person data with each Order, you just loop the Orders and you have no more database calls.  If you use lazy-loading of the Person data instead, then as you loop the orders you have to make an additional database call per Order to get the Person data.  That's a lot of calls.

If appropriate, you could also split the difference and design load methods to which you can pass a flag of "LoadChildren."  Doing so gives you the ultimate flexibility, but maintainability/readability is sacrificed because depending on where you are in code, you won't necessarily know if the Person data is populated or not.